# Figures next to each other - simply

Tags: floats, includegraphics

What is wrong with this code that figures are not next to each other? The size of picture is fine, it will fit.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel} 

\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\centerline{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{fig1.jpg}}
\centerline{\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{fig2.jpg}}
\caption{Name, \cite{img}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I suggest that you post a minimal working example.

Comment: I editted the question

Comment: Could you also add an image of your current result so we can also *see* your issue? (That is helpful because we don't have your "fig" files.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you try

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth,clip=]{fig.jpg}
\includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth,clip=]{img.jpg}
\caption{Cap, \protect\cite{image}}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: I tried to add centering, but it doesn't help

Comment: @Moe ... you have to remove your `\centerline` too from each `\includegraphics` because it centers each one in a separate "line" ... also an `\hspace{1cm}` between the two `\includegraphics` could improve the output.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: In some cases you could still have problems compiling this code ... a command like `\caption{Cap, \cite{image}}` could cause errors in compilation in some different versions ... Change this too into `\caption{Cap, \protect\cite{image}}`... (Jose ... please edit to add this if you think it is useful).

Comment: @koleygr It's done.

Comment: Please, avoid suggesting the `[H]` option.

Comment: @egreg I've edited my answer, but why is that?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Figures (and tables) float because there is usually (by Murphy's law) no place for them in the preferred place: this is also know as the “elephant in a suitcase problem”.